# RGB values obtained from Android.Graphics.Bitmap.GetPixels are slightly different from System.Drawing.Bitmap.GetPixel

Tags: android, .net, colors, rgb, bmp

I am trying to migrate a windows image processing application to Android app. But when I try to get the RGB value from same bmp picture, I find that values have slightly changed. For example, the RGB values for a pixel are 137, 106, 54 in windows app, while in android app, they change to 140, 105, 57. The function to get RGB value I used in windows is System.Drawing.Bitmap.GetPixel, and in android app, it is Android.Graphics.Bitmap.GetPixels. The return type of the two functions are both "color" type, which defines the ARGB values. The phone I am using to test the app is an old one running android 2.2.2. What's the reason for this problem? Should I try newer version of android? Thanks for all comments in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It proved to be the problem of the android version. After I tried a phone with newer version, the RGB values completely match those under Windows System. I shouldn't have use that old phone for test. Hope this can help others who come across the same problem.